# IF condition is getting failed ..solution plz

Tags: if-statement, karate, karate-call-single

- eval if (success == 'Data1') karate.call('test.feature')

this is getting failed displaying error message as
Expected ; but found {  }

Tried below :

- eval if (success == 'Data1') karate.call('test.feature');

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can't just expect us to understand the context and provide the right answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Changing your step to below would work

```
* eval (success == 'Data1') ? karate.call('test.feature') : karate.call('fail.feature')
```